bookdown. Rmd not converted to TeX and pdf
I have just installed Rstudio with Bookdown on my new Mac mini M2. When building a book, the HTML and E-PUB outputs are fine, but the PDF output is not. Even the TeX file is not created. This applies only to books. As to basic Rmd files, they do knit fine to every output, including Tex and PDF.
The _output.yml settings are
bookdown::pdf_book:
includes:
in_header: preamble.tex
latex_engine: pdflatex
citation_package: natbib
keep_tex: yes
The build message is
==> rmarkdown::render_site(output_format = 'bookdown::pdf_book', encoding = 'UTF-8')
*processing file: FoundationMaths.Rmd
*/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/tools/aarch64/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS FoundationMaths.knit.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output FoundationMaths.tex --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library/bookdown/rmarkdown/lua/custom-environment.lua --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua --metadata-file /var/folders/dw/s_5bnz3s2kg8wcvj17n05y8m0000gn/T//RtmpHTtOOY/file125b81b9a35ca --embed-resources --standalone --table-of-contents --toc-depth 2 --number-sections --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --natbib --include-in-header preamble.tex --variable graphics --wrap preserve --variable tables=yes --standalone -Mhas-frontmatter=false
output file: FoundationMaths.knit.md
*
Error running filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua:
.../Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua:52: attempt to index a nil value (field 'integer index')
stack traceback:
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 83
Execution halted*
Exited with status 1.
I checked all the details I could think of against the R-studio and bookdown installed on my laptop and working fine and found no difference.
Internet search yields a similar issue resolved via reinstalling of rmarkdonw and bookdown. This did not work for me.
